# How to handle Concurrency Conflicts with HttpClient?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, concurrency, httpclient

I can't figure out how to edit the row after seeing the changes in DB.

- I have an API-project and an MVC-project. I use CRUD in my API and call them with my MVC with HttpClient
- I have a `public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }` property with the attribute `[Timestamp]`.
- I have a clientFactory where I do CreateClient() to perform `PutAsync("api.example.com/{id}")` action.
- The `HttpResponseMessage variable` on my putasync action returns `StatusCode(409)` because my API successfully detected a concurrency conflict.
- I managed to display error messages before updating the concurrency; showing the newly updated rows in the database(newsDb) with help of a **new client**, `clientFactory.CreateClient()`, and comparing them with the inputs(news).
- Then I set the `news.RowVersion = newsDb.RowVersion` and re-display View(news).

And after clicking Save again, nothing happens - no redirects, no changes - the concurrency errors are still there:

```
[HttpPost("edit/{id}")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> EditNewsArticle(int id, [Bind("NewsId,Author,Title,Content,CreatedDate,HashTags,RowVersion")] News news)
{
    if (id != news.NewsId)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        news.UpdatedDate = DateTime.Now;
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(news);
        HttpResponseMessage putTask = await clientFactory.CreateClient().PutAsync($"https://localhost:44331/api/News/{id}", new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));

        if (putTask.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        else if (putTask.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Conflict)
        {
            string jsonDb = await clientFactory.CreateClient().GetStringAsync($"https://localhost:44331/api/News/{id}");
            News newsDb = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<News>(jsonDb);

            if (newsDb is null)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, $"Unfortunately, the news item you edited has already been deleted by another user.");
            }

            if (newsDb.Title != news.Title)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("Title", $"Title in database: {newsDb.Title}");
            }
            if (newsDb.Author != news.Author)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("Author", $"Author in database: {newsDb.Author}");
            }
            if (newsDb.Content != news.Content)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("Content", $"Content in database: {newsDb.Content}");
            }
            if (newsDb.HashTags != news.HashTags)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("HashTags", $"HashTags in database: {newsDb.HashTags}");
            }

            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty,
            "Editing was canceled as the selected news item was changed by someone else in the meantime." +
            "The values ​​of the change are now shown below, which are derived from the database" + 
            "If you still want to edit the user, click Save again.");

            news.RowVersion = newsDb.RowVersion;
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Unknown error. Contact a support.");
            return View(news);
        }
    }

    return View(news);
}
```

[image: Concurrency successfully displays, but Save doesn't apply these new changes, after acknowledging they were changed]

API Put:

```
[HttpPut("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> PutNews(int id, [FromBody] News news)
{
    if (id != news.NewsId)
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }

    context.Entry(news).State = EntityState.Modified;

    try
    {
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
    {
        if (!NewsExists(id))
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        else
        {
            return StatusCode(409);
        }
    }

    return CreatedAtAction("GetNews", new { id = news.NewsId }, news);
}
```

Comment: I dont think that concurrency errors on update are problems with front-end stuff, this is responsability of the API, can you post the api code? Also, when you click save, how many requests are created on the network tab?

Comment: @MestreDosMagros I updated the question and added code for API httpput

Comment: You are adding concurrency errors to ModelState and upon second save click they are still there and your ModelState is not valid.

Comment: @Quercus I debugged it and the ModelState is still valid, and going inside the concurrency again. Edit: And I tried removing the if(ModelState.IsValid)

Comment: dont need this: context.Entry(news).State = EntityState.Modified; get the entity from db and update the values and then call SaveChanges()

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/concurrency

Answer (score 0):

I found my issue. I needed to call ModelState.Clear(); after de-serializing the 'jsonDb', and also remove RowVersion from Bind in the attribute.